# How to check whether a connection for a specific port is open using python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to check whether a connection with some port is running on windows. I can do it using netstat, but how can I check it using python?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import socket;
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
res = s.connect_ex(('192.1.1.1',80))
if res == 0:
   print "Open"
else:
   print "Closed"
```